# Accessing class member pointers

Tags: c++

Suppose I have the following definition of List and Node:

---

```
template <class T> 
class List {
    public:
        class Iterator;
        class ConstIterator;

        //Constructors and Destructors.
        List() : head(NULL), tail(NULL), size(0) {}
        List(const List& list);
        ~List();

        //Methods
        Iterator begin();
        ConstIterator begin() const;
        Iterator end();
        ConstIterator end() const;
        void insert(const T& data);
        void insert(const T& data, const Iterator& iterator);
        void remove(const Iterator& iterator);
        int getSize() const;
        Iterator find(const T& item);
        ConstIterator find(const T& item) const;
        void sort();

        //Operators
        List operator = (const List& list);


    private:
        class Node;
        Node* head;
        Node* tail;
        int size;
};


template <class T>
class List<T>::Node
{
    public:
        //Constructors and destructors
        Node(const T& _data, const Node* _next) : data(_data), next(_next) {}       
        ~Node(); //Destructor 

        //Methods


        //Operators
        Node operator = (const Node& node);

    private:
        T data;
        Node* next;
};
```

---

I'm writing a function to insert data into a list like this:

---

```
    template<class T>
    void List<T>::insert(const T& data)
    {
    Node newNode = new Node(data, NULL);

    if (head == NULL)
    {
        head = &newNode;
        tail = &newNode;
    }
    else
    {
        (*tail)->next = &newNode;
        tail = &newNode;
    }
    size++;
}
```

---

However what I find strange is that if I swap `(*tail)->next = &newNode;` to `(*tail).next = &newNode;` it still compiles. Why, and what is the correct way of doing it?

Comment: Can you show the definition of `Node` ?

Comment: I did, just scroll down.

Comment: Wait. `template <class T> class List<T>::Node` means `Node` is privately inherited by `List`. Isn't it ? Or am I missing something here ?

Comment: You're not missing anything.  The problem is the templates.  They don't get compiled until instantiated so crazy mistakes look like they compile.  This happens a lot.

Comment: If this is not homework then just use the STL instead - it is all done for you! If it is homework perhaps passing parameters in as references would maker things easier. Also use nullptr instead of NULL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definitions of your classes can be (for the purposes of this question) simplified into:

```
class List {
    ...
    private:
        Node* head;
        Node* tail;
};

class Node {
    ...
    private:
        Node* next;
};
```

Now in your `List::insert` method:

```
Node newNode = new Node(data, NULL);
(*tail)->next = &newNode;
```

...when you use `new` expression, the result will be pointer to the newly allocated memory.
What you should do is:

```
Node* newNode = new Node(data, NULL);
tail->next = newNode;                // <-- equivalent to (*tail).next = newNode;
```

Comment: A strange assingment `(*tail)->next`. I guess to this be valid, tail must be defined as a double pointer (`Node **tail`)

Answer (score 0):

The -> operator will automatically derefference a pointer for you then call the method to the right.  So:

```
tail->next
```

would also work but

```
tail.next
```

wouldn't because tail is a pointer.  To use the . operator you have to defrence the pointer first as in

```
(*tail).next

(*tail)
```

turns your pointer into an object.  At that point you can use either -> or .

A . will not work on a pointer but -> will.

Generally, just for easy of typing I use -> because it is shorter then using (*)  to turn a pointer into an object just so I can use a dot but they are equivalent operations.

Comment: I think you didn't get the question correctly. OP says it **still** compiles if changed one to other. In my view, it shouldn't.

Comment: If the syntax is similar to C, I have hard time understanding why this compiles.

Comment: @Mahesh Sorry if I wasn't clear.  Both syntaxes are valid and do compile because they are equivalent.  tail is a pointer.  *tail is an object.  -> can be used on objects or pointers, . can only be used on an object.  Since he turns his pointer into an object he can use either

Answer (score 0):

Using Node->tail is short form of writing (*Node).tail. Both forms are valid. Strangeus is the fact that you say that (*Node)->tail compiles. To this happens, Node must be defined as a double pointer, i.e.:

```
Node **tail;
```

But your code has some others bugs in. In this line:

```
Node newNode = new Node(data, NULL);
```

you are define a local object and assing a dynamic memory to it. The correct way is:

```
Node *newNode = new Node(data, NULL);  // defining it as a pointer
```

and instead of assing as:

```
head = &newNode;
```

do:

```
head = newNode;
```

As a final note, consider using smart pointer instead of raw pointer. The former is safer than the last

Answer (score 0):

You have noticed that `(*tail)->next = &newNode` and `(*tail).next = &newNode` both compile, which strikes you as odd.

But somehow you might also have noticed that this line also compiles!

```
Node newNode = new Node(data, NULL);
```

*That* is the thing that you should give you pause.

You are inside of a template here.  Lots of things "compile".

Did you try instantiating the template?

ADDENDUM:

Here just to show you how crazy things can be, check out this program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class C {
  void f();
};

template <class T>
void C<T>::f() {
  int x = new int;
}

int main() {
  std::cout << "Hello, world\n";
}
```

Now check this out:

```
$ g++ template-example.cpp && ./a.out 
Hello, world
```

But now notice

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  int x = new int;
  std::cout << "Hello, world\n";
}
```

which yields:

```
$ g++ hello.cpp
hello.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
hello.cpp:4: error: invalid conversion from ‘int*’ to ‘int’
```

TL;DR: *WHEN YOU ARE IN A TEMPLATE, THINGS THAT SHOULD NOT COMPILE SOMETIMES "DO"!*  (They're not really compiling -- YET!)